# android progress bar for android browser

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I am making android browser app and completed 90%. I just want to know how can,I put some progress bar on my application so that people can see that page is loading and they have to wait.

like this while the browser is uploading a page somewhat a this type of bar shows at top of the sccreen

http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/progressbars-fine.png

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The developer docs for [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) show you how to do this.

You need to set a [WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html) on the WebView, and override the onProgressChanged method. Inside of this method you can then set the progress on the progressbar in your apps UI.